# Tomcat native library not found on java path

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

This is the stacktrace when I run `tomcat`. `Java and Maven` exist.

Now, I checked my folders and there is a `tools.jar` in file path `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib`

What am I missing?

I am currently using **Tomcat v6.0, jre7** and have **jdk1.6.0_34** installed

**Stacktrace**

> The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\CA\SharedComponents\ScanEngine;C:\Program
>   Files\CA\SharedComponents\CAUpdate\;C:\Program
>   Files\CA\SharedComponents\ThirdParty\;C:\Program
>   Files\CA\SharedComponents\SubscriptionLicense\;C:\Program
>   Files\CA\eTrustITM;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin;C:\maven\bin;C:\maven\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Perforce;.

Comment: Maybe you just did a wrong copy and paste. In the variable `java.library.path`, you have `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin`, while I think you want one of the two to be `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib`

Comment: what should i change the variable to?

Comment: Probably you have another problem - an app is not deployed or deployed at unexpected path. The message above is unrelated.

Comment: This stacktrace is not be the cause of your 404. I think you'll find it is an `info` level log - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean. Are there any other errors?

Comment: try running tomcat with `-cp CLASSPATH` after setting a variable called `CLASSPATH` to the value `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib`. If this doesn't work, or you have problem, please add your tomcat configuration to the question

Comment: Are you **actively** trying to add APR support to Tomcat ? If you are not, the error you posted here is just informational, and **nothing** you need to pay attention to. If you have other issues with your webapp, it is **unrelated** to the log you have posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything.The [APR tc native](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) is only used for better performing IO and not mandatory.

Comment: Are you using SSL certificates for an HTPS connector?That's the only case where having tc native or not would make a difference (if the connector is configured with APR SSL in mind). If not please expand on your 404 error (posting your web.xml would also be a good idea). If you want to be sure go the link i posted in my answer and install tc native to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Your 404 is unrelated to this message.