# Unable to deploy .war file in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using tomcat 7.
I have integrated tomcat on windows machine. I want to deploy war file on this server. When I restart my tomcat I am getting following error in log:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in 
production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Mail Enable\BIN;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin;C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft 
ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance 
Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 
Utilities 1.3.4\;D:\xampp\htdocs\api\lib\Cake\Console;.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat's config xml (conf\server.xml), try to comment out this line of the APR config:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

Comment: i meant to comment it OUT. to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

This isnt an `error` with Tomcat. It is an `Info`. Most likely your application deploy is failing due to the application having issues. 
If you can reach `http://localhost:8080` without issues, it isnt a tomcat problem.

Check for catalina.log or if using tomcat as a service, tomcat_service.log(i might be misspelling the filename)

The problem has to be with the deployable war file, it isnt a tomcat issue from what you have mentioned.
Check the log files of the application if they get created and if there is an error in them. 
the typical place would be the `logs` folder within tomcat to check for logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is just an info message.

For more details check here.

[What does "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean)

Comment: But I am unable to deploy this file on my tomcat server.

Comment: What other errors do you get? And from what do you conclude you cannot deploy your war file?

Comment: I am unable to access http://localhost:8080/d/ where d is application directory name. And I am also getting following error while deploying:  INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\d.war
Jan 13, 2014 3:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 13, 2014 3:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/d] startup failed due to previous errors

Answer (score 0):

Go the tomcat directory

```
tomcat7\bin>service.bat install //(this will install tomcat)
tomcat7\bin>tomcat7.exe //(this will start tomcat)
```

before deploying the war try `http://localhost:8080/`
if you see tomcat webpage, everything is good else their is a problem.

then Deploy the war file in webapps folder in tomcat directory and start the server.

Comment: I have already installed tomcat and also getting http://localhost:8080/, but I am getting problem while deploying war file.

Comment: try "java -version" on your command prompt and let me know whats the output.

Comment: I am getting: java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)