# where to add Apr based Native Library for tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, apr, java.library.path

While Running Tomcat I am getting this.I read about it that I have to add Apr based native library for tomcat. i had downloaded this Apr native dll zip file from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi) .But Can you please tell where i have to install or put it.I go through this stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean).but I am not getting where to put/Edit this Apr thing....
And I am getting this error

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\bin;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;;;C:\eclipse;;.

Answer (score 3):

The tcnative-1.dll file goes in the Tomcat bin directory. I also added the Tomcat bin directory to my PATH environment variable.

EDIT:

I added the following to the end of my PATH variable: C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.44\bin

apache-tomcat-6.0.44 is my tomcat installation directory. I do not know if adding the bin directory to PATH is necessary, but it was something I did when trying to get APR to configure.

Yes tcnative-1.dll goes in the bin directory. Also, note that by default it is usually included with the Tomcat download and, at least for me, it turns out that APR was enabled by default. Also of interest might be [server.xml configuration](https://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.6/admin/manual-apr.html). This explains how to modify server.xml in the conf directory do enable/disable APR.

Comment: After downloading that native.dll . Do we have to put it in tomcat bin directory ?can you please share your path environment variable value.