# pentaho can't access by chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, pentaho, business-intelligence, properties-file

### **1. Symptom**

1.1 **frontend**

When I download and configure pentaho on my redhat server, it works on IE, but can't access by chrome with the admin account. you may see the attached pic below, loading all the time
[image]

**1.2 Chrome**

> Updated 1.2 on 2016/06/15 based on fvu comment

There are also some mistakes on Chrome, below is the screenshot

[image]

**1.3 backend**

I find some useful information in the log, but can't find anything useful on google. the log is below:

```
Reference number: 334266e0-aecf-41c6-afb5-7fb966b76d84
2015-06-12 15:01:07,539 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.ConnectionServiceImpl] ConnectionServiceImpl.ERROR_0002 - Unable to get the list of connections: DatasourceMgmtService.ERROR_0004 - Error occurred during retrieving the datasource . Cause: exception while getting children for folder with id "cde5df46-b71d-40e0-b728-b506dec1abbb"

Reference number: c17467b1-a9a8-4d54-9bd3-defb0531ec13
2015-06-12 15:01:07,964 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.DSWDatasourceServiceImpl] DatasourceServiceImpl.ERROR_0022 - Unable to process logical model for domain id: steel-wheels.
org.pentaho.platform.api.repository2.unified.UnifiedRepositoryException: PentahoMetadataDomainRepository.ERROR_0005 - Error retrieving domain with id [steel-wheels] - exception while getting data for file with id "ccd90ccc-5d7c-4b47-be28-2f36612703ad"

Reference number: 9f7ae68e-4bd9-4511-928e-a32c2d2e7bc6
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.metadata.PentahoMetadataDomainRepository.getDomain(PentahoMetadataDomainRepository.java:312)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.metadata.SessionCachingMetadataDomainRepository.getDomain(SessionCachingMetadataDomainRepository.java:193)
    at org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.DSWDatasourceServiceImpl.getLogicalModels(DSWDatasourceServiceImpl.java:427)
    at org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.DatasourceResource.getDSWDatasourceIds(DatasourceResource.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor125.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.JAXRSPluginServlet.service(JAXRSPluginServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.JAXRSPluginServlet.service(JAXRSPluginServlet.java:67)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.PluginDispatchServlet.service(PluginDispatchServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.java:265)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.WebappRootForwardingFilter.doFilter(WebappRootForwardingFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.repository2.unified.UnifiedRepositoryException: exception while getting data for file with id "ccd90ccc-5d7c-4b47-be28-2f36612703ad"
```

### **2. Environment**

- server OS:   Linux version 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64（Red Hat 4.4.4-13）
- Pentaho: 5.0.1 stable community edition
- Chrome:  43.0.2357.124 m
- Laptop:  Windows 7 Home edition, Chinese characters only

### **3. Reference**

the following list is the document I find useful, especial the last one I use this document to configure my pentaho system.

- http://helicaltech.com/pentaho-5-0-1-ce-integration-mysql-5-0-1-ce-windows-linux-family/#.VXjcvPmqpBc
- http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?59987-Server-in-the-Tomcat-or-Java!!
- https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/index.html
- [What does "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean)
- http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Finstall_manual%2Ftask_configure_rdbms_repository.html

Is there anyone have any clues about my questions ?

1. Why I followed every steps on the manual, there is still error logs in the tomcat/logs/pentaho.logs?
2. why now I can't access by chrome but can access by IE with admin account?

Thanks in advance! I suffered a lot recently because of pentaho.

Comment: I don't think the issues in Chrome will be related to the backend logs you are showing, I think you need to work on these separately. For the Chrome issues your first stop should be Chrome's developer tools and more specifically the Network and Console views, to see whether all files get picked up correctly, and whether there are Javascript issues.

Comment: Hi fvu, thanks for your quick response. All the logs are generated when I am using chrome to log on, so I think they are related. the logs and chrome.

Comment: That is indeed useful information, you may want to add it to your question. Did you have a look at the console and network information in Chrome?

Comment: Hi fvu, I will check the console and network information in chrome on next Monday.

Comment: @fvu I checked the console information in Chrome, you may find the screenshot above, it's all about 404.

Comment: I had the same issue as you, it was fixed after I disabled the Norton-related addons from Chrome Extensions.

Comment: @lihao  I didn't install the Norton-related addons on my Chrome,  and the 404 errors I think didn't related to addons.

Answer (score 0):

This steps worked for me:

1. Stop the service
2. Remove/rename folder pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/repository
3. Start the service

The folder is re-created at startup, no worries