# The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, server, catalina

When I debug tomcat, the broswer start but get 404:

> HTTP Status 404 - /
>
> type Status report
>
> message /
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.75

The Tomcat Catalina Log and Server Log all have this below error:

> The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/luowensheng/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.

I searched SO, find a similar post:

[What does "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean)

My software environment is:

```
Mac OS 
IntelliJ IDEA
```

Comment: The warning you see in the log has no relation to your 404 problem. You will have to provide more details, ideally the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: do you want to fix your APR log warning or Eror 404?

Comment: @CrazyCoder which part detail do you want?

Answer (score 5):

> HTTP Status 404 - /

This error is caused due to many problems for example:

1. Mostly this error is thrown due to invalid path. make sure the following folders exists:

> ```
> >  $cataline_home/webapps/your-project|
> >                                         -->html,css,images, etc.                                       
> >                                         -->WEB-INF|
> >                                                    -->classes (your java files)
> >                                                    -->lib     (your libraries)
> ```

2. Make sure java is install on your machine. You can check it by running simply `javac` on command prompt or using java -version
3. You are typing wrong URL address or incomplete URL or URL without tomcat port
4. Also make sure you added your classes properly in web.xml file

> installing Tomcat APR in MAC is [HERE](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/01/add-apr-based-native-library-for-tomcat.html)
>   and for Linux following is tested by myself

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path

**Prerequisites for installing APR**
    APR library
    APR-util library
    OpenSSL library

```
yum install openssl-devel
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

mkdir tomcat-apr
cd tomcat-apr
wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist//apr/apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd apr-1.5.2
./configure
make
make install
```

The default installation path is /usr/local/apr

```
Download and Install APR-util                  
wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist//apr/apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
cd apr-util-1.5.4
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr
make
make install
```

The default path of installation is /usr/local/apr/lib
Install JNI Wrapper for APR used by Tomcat (libtcnative)

```
cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
tar -zxvf tomcat-native.tar.gz
cd tomcat-native-1.1.29-src/jni/native
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-java-home=/var/java/jdk1.7.0_45
make
make install
```

The native libraries were installed in /usr/local/apr/lib
Integrate APR with Tomcat
There are two ways to set Tomcat integrate with APR.

One is you can add the following parameter when start up the Tomcat in bin/catalina.sh: 
CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/apr/lib"

The other is to add a new environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/profile:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/apr/lib
```

Then makes it effect via:

```
source /etc/profile
```

After restarting the Tomcat service, we can get the following message in catalina.out log if APR was installed successfully.

> Oct 07, 2015 8:08:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using
>   APR version 1.5.2. Oct 07, 2015 8:08:54 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true].