# The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found

Tags: java, tomcat, apr

I have a problem with Tomcat. When I am creating new project I have following error:

`INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Users\twloszki\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]`

I tried to solve my problem according to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean) however when I add `-Djava.library.path=c:\dev\tomcat\bin` to eclipse.init it does not help.

Comment: Tomcat runs in a separate JVM process. You need to modify the environment of the Tomcat process, not Eclipse. Pretty sure similar questions have been asked and answered many times on SO and the rest of the internet for the past two decades.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I placed the new tcnative-1.dll from http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.2.16/binaries/tomcat-native-1.2.16-win32-bin.zip where tomcat was installed for me it was C:\xampp\tomcat\bin. And it solved my problem.