# I have this error: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:[C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Syste.....

Comment: Please check related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean

Comment: Thx, but does't work.