# In console after starting tomcat server i am getting Error. when my spring mvc projetc get deployed on tomcat7

Tags: spring-mvc

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_261/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_261/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_261/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin;"C:\Windows\System32;";C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin;C:\Users\avina\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3\bin;;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin;C:\Users\avina\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin;;F:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-mvc-demo' did not find a matching property.
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 437 ms
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body`enter code here`
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:40 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [370] milliseconds.
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: Completed initialization in 673 ms
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\avina\New folder (2)\webapps\docs
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\avina\New folder (2)\webapps\examples
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@2ea3122e')
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\avina\New folder (2)\webapps\host-manager
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\avina\New folder (2)\webapps\manager
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\avina\New folder (2)\webapps\ROOT
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 2211 ms
    Sep 30, 2020 11:21:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
```

WARNING: No mapping for GET /spring-mvc-demo/
so basically it gives 404 after launcing and resource not foung message.
plz help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean)

Comment: No @Lakshan i tried that solution but not worked for me. Actually i thin it is realted to mapping,not able to map the request.