# Installation of APR/native for apache-tomee-plus-7.0.6 on Windows Server (with Binaries)

Tags: tomcat7, apache-tomee, apr, tomee-7

I'd like to know how we can install APR/Native library on Apache-tomee-plus-7.0.6, running on Windows server 2008 and using Binaries ?

I need this library to test HTTPS connection using Http11AprProtocol instead of Http11Protocol & Http11NioProtocol.

I retrieved the binaries + dlls from https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.2.25/binaries/tomcat-native-1.2.25-openssl-1.1.1g-win32-bin.zip, stored them on the server and added the path containing them in the PATH environment variable (using setenv.bat in apache-tomee-plus-7.0.6\bin) but I still see the error :

```
14:48:02.176 SEVERE [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNUwn.png)

Comment: Sorry, found the solution on another thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean)