# INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path:

Tags: tomcat, native

I am new Java we development learner. I created a small Program to Upload the files using Java . However I am getting the above error. I am using Eclipse IDE 2020. please can someone help me how to resolve Open SSL issue.? It should be in simple words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean)