# HTTP 404 Not Found -The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, eclipse, http, tomcat

I have apache tomcat console message :

> INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was
> not found on the java.library.path:

Will this cause me error when I run project with `doGet` and `doPost` methods for `servlet`.

Comment: When I run any dynamic web content project in tomcat apache server with java servlet, I get error HTTP 404 OR 405 Error when I click on link related to doGet or doPost methods. Is it due the missing contents of Apache Tomcat Native?

Comment: What link, and you should probably ask in a new question and include sources and mapping information so readers are sure that it's supposed to work and not just a mistake on your part.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/soccer/list_leagues.view] is not available

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean/8717883#8717883

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716259/what-does-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-mean) (thank you @GreyFairer - voting to close as duplicate)

Comment: And what should make us expect `/soccer/list_leagues.view` to work?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is an **INFO** message telling you that it just won't perform as well as it could if it did find that library. Errors would be indicated with **ERROR**.